# Remotely SSH into Ubuntu KVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, linux-kvm

**Overview**
I've create a KVM based virtual machine guest that is running Ubuntu Bionic Beaver server image on an Ubuntu Bionic Beaver host. Now that it is up an running, I'd like to have the ability to access the VM remotely. The idea is to run RealSync from my remote laptop which would update the VMs codebase.

**VM Software**
I am using Kernel-based Virtual Machine VM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) with libvirt.

- kvm --version
  QEMU emulator version 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.21)
  Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
- --version=long
  Virsh command line tool of libvirt 4.0.0
  See web site at https://libvirt.org/
  Compiled with support for:
  Hypervisors: QEMU/KVM LXC UML Xen LibXL OpenVZ VMware VirtualBox ESX Test
  Networking: Remote Network Bridging Interface netcf Nwfilter VirtualPort
  Storage: Dir Disk Filesystem SCSI Multipath iSCSI LVM RBD Sheepdog Gluster ZFS
  Miscellaneous: Daemon Nodedev AppArmor Secrets Debug DTrace Readline
- TP-Link Router
- OS Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-74-generic x86_64)

**issue**
After looking through a ton of articles, I still haven't found clear instructions on how to do this. It looks like I might want to configure a *br0* bridge to the vm? Or potentially set up some sort of port forwarding? Any help on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include info on what VM software you are using. At the end of the day the overall concept is your VM will be a part of your network, and then your router would allow traffic through your internet connection and routed to the VM via port forwarding.

Comment: This sounds like a home network, so you'd probably go with a) port forwarding enabled on your TP Link router, b) using a DDNS service and c) using port forwarding on your Ubuntu host, while doing outbount NAT there.